how to make cards in a row
I have 9 product cards. When adding 5 products, they go in a row, but when adding the sixth and further, then the goods go from top to bottom. Flex doesn't help, how can I fix it? What is the problem? I tried using display: ruby, flex wrap. None of this helped. I'm new to this, I'm asking for your help.


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  /*was max-width*/
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
  .wrapper li {
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .nft {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<div class="product-card-container">
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You messed up some of the div tags which did not allowed product-card-container to be implemented after the 5th card in your html file


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  /*was max-width*/
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
  .wrapper li {
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .nft {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
  <div class="product-card-container">
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage' alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage' alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage' alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage' alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage'  alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage'  alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage' alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage'  alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
      <div class='main'>
        <img class='tokenImage'  alt="NFT" />
        <h2>Корзинка</h2>
        <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>



